# Toast does not work in Android 4.3

Tags: java, android, apk, toast

I'm building an apk and I use Toast to show some information.

Toast works correctly in 4.2.2 but it does not work (no Toast message is displayed) in Android 4.3.

Ex:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Display a log message to be sure you actually tried to display the Toast.   By "not works" I assume you mean you saw nothing?

Comment: try to get your context not by using getApplicationContext(). It is not adviced for displaying dialog/toast/alert...

Comment: Also, some other info would be nice. Where are you calling this line from? and did you test this very same code in 4.2?

Comment: define "it not works"

Comment: Make sure that you does not call the Toast from AsyncTask class specially in the doInBackground

Comment: There is a "feature"/bug in Jelly Bean that basically swallows toasts and makes them invisible. Check in the app settings if notifications are enabled for your app. See here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

Comment: Great, thank you @NobuGames ! It's exactly what you write here.

Answer (score 0):

This may help others!

*Possible reason :*

1) Context is not working

2) You might have unchecked "Show notification" in your app settings.

To check it Goto **Settings > Apps > Your App > Check "Show Notification" box**.
In android if you disable show notification then Toast messages are also get disabled.

Answer (score 0):

use  "this" instead of getApplicationContext()